# Why does subdomain.localhost work on Ubuntu but not on Debian? (without hosts entry)

Tags: subdomain, apache2, localhost, lamp

I have set up LAMP stacks on both Ubuntu 20.04 and Debian 10 running Apache 2.4.

The VirtualHost Files are identical as follows :

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName subdomain.localhost
    ServerAlias www.subdomain.localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/localhost/subdomain

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I have dissabled the default site and enabled the localhost site on both machines.

On Ubuntu i can just visit subdomain.localhost (and [www.subdomain.locahost](http://www.subdomain.locahost)) via my browser. On Debian, however, I have to add an entry to the /etc/hosts file for every subdomain I'd like to create/use.

1. Why is that? Whats the difference between Debain and Ubuntu that causes that?
2. Am I able to configure Debian in a way so that I do not need to add an entry for every subdomain for localhost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu is running the service `systemd-resolved` that maps localhost subdomains to your local IP address.

If you query the DNS using `dig` you will see that it gets the local IP address (`127.0.0.1`) from a SERVER running on a localhost IP address (`127.0.0.53`):

```
$ dig www.subdomain.localhost
...
www.subdomain.localhost. 0  IN  A   127.0.0.1
...
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
```

The configuration file that sets up the DNS servers to use (`resolv.conf`) specifies to use this local DNS server:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
...
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

You can verify that the `systemd-resolved` service is running with

```
$ sudo service systemd-resolved status
● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) ...
```

This service is available on Debian: https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/systemd/systemd-resolved.service.8.en.html but it is not enabled by default.  You should be able to start the service on Debian  by following the instructions from this Server Fault question: [Is that possible for debian users to connect to network through systemd-networkd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263826/is-that-possible-for-debian-users-to-connect-to-network-through-systemd-networkd)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Whilest configuring Debian i had to add my localhost IP to the resolv.conf  file to makle it work and i had to leave the default IP in there, without the default one i could not connect to the internet. It kinda feels like a dirty hack.?
Before :
`# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.***.**.*`
After :
`# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.0.53
nameserver 192.***.**.*` (The stars (*) are for privacy reasons)

Comment: My instructions for enabling `systemd-resolved` were optimistically incomplete.   It looks like you can follow the instructions at [Is that possible for debian users to connect to network through systemd-networkd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263826/is-that-possible-for-debian-users-to-connect-to-network-through-systemd-networkd) for a more complete setup.

Comment: Thanks again, may good things happen to you.